# How to Predict value in Spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, prediction

I am **Very** new to Spark Machine Learning **(4 days old)** i am executing the below code in Spark Shell i am trying to predict some value

My requirement is I have data which consist of following

Columns

```
 Userid,Date,SwipeIntime
 1, 1-Jan-2017,9.30
 1, 2-Jan-2017,9.35
 1, 3-Jan-2017,9.45
 1, 4-Jan-2017,9.26
 2, 1-Jan-2017,9.37
 2, 2-Jan-2017,9.35
 2, 3-Jan-2017,9.45
 2, 4-Jan-2017,9.46
```

I need to predict what **will be the SwipeIntime for** Userid = 1 will come on Date 5-Jan-2017 or any date

What i have tried is the below code in Spark Shell

**Code:**

```
 case class LabeledDocument(Userid: Double, Date: String, label: Double)
 val training = spark.read.option("inferSchema", true).csv("/root/Predictiondata2.csv").toDF
 ("Userid","Date","label").toDF().as[LabeledDocument]
 import scala.beans.BeanInfo
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
 import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
 import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
 import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, Tokenizer}
 import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
 import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
 val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("Date").setOutputCol("words")
 val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setNumFeatures(1000).setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("features")
 import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
 val lr = new LinearRegression().setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)
 val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))
 val model = pipeline.fit(training.toDF())
 case class Document(Userid: Integer, Date: String)
 val test = sc.parallelize(Seq(Document(4, "04-Jan-18"),Document(5, "01-Jan-17"),Document(2, "03-Jan-17")))
 model.transform(test.toDF()).show()
```

Getting Incorrect Output **(Same SwipeIntime for all Users)**

```
 scala> model.transform(test.toDF()).show() 
 +------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
 |Userid|     Date|      words|          features|       prediction|
 +------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
 |     4|04-Jan-18|[04-jan-18]|(1000,[455],[1.0])|9.726888888888887|
 |     5|01-Jan-17|[01-jan-17]|(1000,[595],[1.0])|9.726888888888887|
 |     2|03-Jan-17|[03-jan-17]|(1000,[987],[1.0])|9.726888888888887|
 +------+---------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

I would be thankful if anyone provide any suggestion to above code to make things working.

Comment: first, your dataset is too small ...

Comment: How much data is needed? Let me know so I can create..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032147/solve-a-prediction-based-problem-using-spark-scala-in-eclipse Guys any Idea. Please give me solution if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you think it's not working? Because the prediction are all the same?

I had a similar issue as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480077/issue-with-spark-mllib-that-causes-probability-and-prediction-to-be-the-same-for) but in PySpark.

I solved it by raising the MaxIter and lowering RegParam and ElasticNetParam.

Try setting them this way:

```
val lr = new LinearRegression().setMaxIter(100).setRegParam(0.001).setElasticNetParam(0.0001)
```

Hope it works!

Comment: do you have any idea about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627422/how-to-provide-multiple-columns-to-setinputcol